# Can not get a precision of a floating number even with Decimal or mpf in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, decimal-point

I need to display a number, let's say 0.9 exact at least until 17 decimal places. Even if I use Decimal or mpf, it gives me the result as if I would not be using them at all.

```
from mpmath import mpf
from decimal import Decimal
from decimal import getcontext
import mpmath

getcontext().prec = 25
mpmath.mp.prec=100

a=mpf("0.9")
b=mpf(0.9)
c=Decimal("0.9")
d=Decimal(0.9)
e=0.9


print("%.17f" % a)
print("%.17f" % b)
print("%.17f" % c)
print("%.17f" % d)
print("%.17f" % e)
```

The output is

```
>>0.90000000000000002
>>0.90000000000000002
>>0.90000000000000002
>>0.90000000000000002
>>0.90000000000000002
```

I have searched everywhere, but I can not seem to find aa solution. Is it even possible to get that precision? What I understood from mpf, they claim a much higher precision than I am getting. What am I missing?

**Edited:**

I am sorry for a potential misunderstanding, but what I really had in mind, is that I need to perform actual calculations with this number, not only to display it properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @It_is_Chris: No, that does not answer the question. This question is about why operations intended to be decimal do not work on decimal values, i.e., why there is a binary-induced rounding error where none is expected. Please do not promiscuously mark floating-point questions as duplicates of that question. Just because a question involves floating-point does not mean it is the same as that question, and closing questions indiscriminately interferes with providing good answers and useful knowledge.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did not close the question; simply voted to.

Comment: @It_is_Chris: Please do not promiscuously mark floating-point questions as duplicates of that question. Just because a question involves floating-point does not mean it is the same as that question, and voting to close questions indiscriminately interferes with providing good answers and useful knowledge.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ha

Comment: Also, I have edited the question, I do not really need to display the value, but I need to make precise calculations with it.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the `%` operator converts its argument to a float when using a `%f` format. Using f-strings instead (or the `.format` method on strings) might be a better idea, since they give the object a better chance of controlling the way it gets formatted.

I just tried this:

```
Python 3.9.0 (v3.9.0:9cf6752276, Oct  5 2020, 11:29:23) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import decimal
>>> d=decimal.Decimal('0.1')
>>> '%.20f' % (d,)
'0.10000000000000000555'
>>> f'{d:.20f}'
'0.10000000000000000000'
```

Comment: It is very weird - when I try this in terminal, I get the same answer as you, but when I deploy the script, nothing changes. It still has that weird value with 5's in the end.